# How could i use electron using my Codeigniter API

Tags: codeigniter, electron

could i use electron to build a desktop App using my PHP Codeigniter APi
and if not how to build a desktop app using php Codeigniter  api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dear Ahmed

you can use `codeigniter` for your `Backend` and use `electron` for `Frontend`

on `Frontend` you need use ajax or similar technology for connect and sync data from `Backend` and not problem to use `Codeigniter`

you can see this tutorial for Codeigniter Restful Api

[Codeigniter Restful API in 15 minutes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X2i-rt0yxDQ)